# How do I protect a node.js app using the saml2-js package?

Tags: node.js, saml-2.0

I've successfully integrated the saml2-js package with my node.js application, and I've confirmed that the authentication process is completing successfully. However, I'm not really sure how to properly put the app or routes behind the authentication. The [saml2-js example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js) doesn't cover that scenario (and maybe that makes sense). So how do I put the app behind the authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully completed our SSO over SAML2.0 task in my organization, so I might be able to help you, at least I can share my experiences.

So here's how we did it

- first of all you need to find out if a certain set of users want to do SSO. This isn't that trivial because before authenticating themself you don't know who wants to login to your system. In our case, we have big corporate users. So we can't just put a "Login by Okta" or "Login by ADFS" button for every customer, because some customer wants the IdP to be Okta, another wants it to be ADFS etc. We solved this by introducing subdomains, and we identify the corporate account by the url. Then we can check what IdP that corporate account wants to use and put a matching SSO button accordingly.
- then, when the user clicks the SSO button you create the login request after which if the user successfully identified himself at the IdP you are ready to create a security context (a.k.a session). Then this session will guard you endpoints and app. When you created the session the user is actually "logged" in to your app.

Comment: Thank you, Jim-Y! The session information got me pointed in the right direction.